# Imprimir el menor de una columna en un array bidimensional

Tags: java, array-bidimensional

Estoy intentando sacar el número menor de un array bidimensional, tras hacer la conversión de string a int, que supongo también se podrá optimizar, el caso es que he consiguido sacar el "mayor" sin problemas, pero el menor se me resiste, siempre me da cero.

```
String [][] bi = new String [4][4];      
        bi [0][0]="10";
        bi [0][1]="8";
        bi [0][2]="5";
        bi [0][3]="10";         
        bi [1][0]="10";
        bi [1][1]="3";
        bi [1][2]="8";
        bi [1][3]="9";          
        bi [2][0]="10";
        bi [2][1]="9";
        bi [2][2]="7";
        bi [2][3]="6";          
        bi [3][0]="10";
        bi [3][1]="10";
        bi [3][2]="4";
        bi [3][3]="9";          
        System.out.println("\nLos elementos del Array son:");
         for (int fila=0; fila<bi.length; fila++){
             System.out.println();
             for(int columna=0; columna<bi.length; columna++){
                 System.out.print(bi[fila][columna]+" ");
             }
             System.out.println("");
         }           
           int  [][] arrayNumero = new int[4][4];    
            for(int i=0;i<bi.length;i++)
            {
                for(int x=0;x<bi.length;x++)
                {
                    bi [0][0]="10";
                    bi [0][1]="8";
                    bi [0][2]="5";
                    bi [0][3]="10";                     
                    bi [1][0]="10";
                    bi [1][1]="3";
                    bi [1][2]="8";
                    bi [1][3]="9";                      
                    bi [2][0]="10";
                    bi [2][1]="9";
                    bi [2][2]="7";
                    bi [2][3]="6";                      
                    bi [3][0]="10";
                    bi [3][1]="10";
                    bi [3][2]="4";
                    bi [3][3]="9";                      
                    arrayNumero[i][x]=Integer.parseInt(bi[i][x]);                       
                }    
            }                    
             int menor=0;                
             for(int i=0; i<arrayNumero.length; i++){   
                 for(int j=0;j>arrayNumero.length; j++) {
                     if(arrayNumero[0][j]<menor) {
                         menor=arrayNumero[0][j];
                     }
                 }
                    } System.out.print("Nota Más Baja del Módulo 01: "+menor);
```

Con un código similar a este he sacado el mayor del array bidimensional, pero el menor se  me resiste, algún alma caritativa. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenías algunos problemas en tu código. Por un lado lo que te comenta @Elmastergear.
Por otro, cuando estas trabajando con arrays bidimensionales tienes que tener en cuenta que para acceder a la propiedad length de la segunda dimensión es necesario indicar la primera posición en el nombre del array. En este caso daba igual porque el array tiene 4 elementos en ambas dimensiones pero si no puede darte errores o no recorrerlo entero.

También he sacado del bucle for la segunda asignación que haces del array ya que no tiene sentido ponerla dentro. Lo que estaba haciendo el programa es hacer la misma asignación tantas veces como se repite el bucle for.

El problema por el que no te entraba en el último bucle for y por tanto no encontraba el número menor:

```
for(int j=0; j<arrayNumero[i].length; j++) {
                 if(arrayNumero[0][j]<menor) {
                     menor=arrayNumero[0][j];

                 }
```

Era porque había puesto `j>arrayNumero.length` entonces nunca entraba en ese bloque de código.

```
public static void main (String args []) {
    String [][] bi = new String [4][4];      
    bi [0][0]="M01";
    bi [0][1]="8";
    bi [0][2]="5";
    bi [0][3]="10";         
    bi [1][0]="M02";
    bi [1][1]="3";
    bi [1][2]="8";
    bi [1][3]="9";          
    bi [2][0]="M03";
    bi [2][1]="9";
    bi [2][2]="7";
    bi [2][3]="6";          
    bi [3][0]="M04";
    bi [3][1]="10";
    bi [3][2]="4";
    bi [3][3]="9";          
    System.out.println("\nLos elementos del Array son:");
     for (int fila=0; fila<bi.length; fila++){
         System.out.println();
         for(int columna=0; columna<bi[fila].length; columna++){
             System.out.print(bi[fila][columna]+" ");
         }
         System.out.println("");
     }           

       bi [0][0]="10";
       bi [0][1]="8";
       bi [0][2]="5";
       bi [0][3]="10";                     
       bi [1][0]="10";
       bi [1][1]="3";
       bi [1][2]="8";
       bi [1][3]="9";                      
       bi [2][0]="10";
       bi [2][1]="9";
       bi [2][2]="7";
       bi [2][3]="6";                      
       bi [3][0]="10";
       bi [3][1]="10";
       bi [3][2]="4";
       bi [3][3]="9";

       int  [][] arrayNumero = new int[4][4]; 

        for(int i=0;i<bi.length;i++)
        {
            for(int x=0;x<bi[i].length;x++)
            {                                        
                arrayNumero[i][x]=Integer.parseInt(bi[i][x]);
            }
        }

         int menor= arrayNumero[0][0];  

         for(int i=0; i<arrayNumero.length; i++){   
             for(int j=0; j<arrayNumero[i].length; j++) {
                 if(arrayNumero[0][j]<menor) {
                     menor=arrayNumero[0][j];

                 } 
             }
            } System.out.println("Nota Más Baja del Módulo 01: "+menor);
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias a todos, Miguel has dado en el clavo. Ahora voy a mirarlo a ver si lo entiendo, que es la finalidad de esto. Muchas Gracias  a todos.

Comment: Si tienes alguna duda pregúntame e intento aclarla en la medida de mis conocimientos.

Comment: como me des confianza te aburro. jajaja. Muchas gracias!!. Es que estoy empezando y ahora son todo dudas. Aunque he acabado el ejercicio, que se trata de un array bidimensional, sobre el que tengo que crear un menú con distintas opciones (switch), acabo de darme cuenta que, aunque me funciona todo, si sigo el orden del menú, cuando vuelvo de la opción tres o cuatro, como he hecho la conversión, ya no me da el mismo resultado, a ver si soy capaz de solventarlo.

Answer (score 1):

bueno te pregunto quieres sacar el menor por columnas o de todo tu `Array` en general?
y otra cosa si te da a 0 es por que nunca se cumple tu condición

```
if(arrayNumero[0][j]<menor) {
   menor=arrayNumero[0][j];
   }
```

siempre comparas números mayores a 0 por lo tanto jamas se cumple el `if` y tu variable menor siempre se queda con su valor inicial que es 0.

si lo que quieres es sacar la menor por columna deberías tener algo así

```
for(int i=0; i<arrayNumero.length; i++){
    int menor=arrayNumero[i][0];   
for(int j=0;j<arrayNumero.length; j++) {
    int  numero=arrayNumero[i][j];  
     if(numero<menor) {
        menor=numero;
        }  
        }
System.out.print("Nota Más Baja del Módulo 0"+(i+1)+":"+menor+"\n");
        }
```

Comment: Ya me había dado cuenta, pero si lo pongo al revés, igualmente da cero. No se lo que hacer.

Comment: checa el nuevo código que te puse

Comment: lo hice, casí das en el clavo. Así saca la más alta de todas las columnas, pero es solo de una columna. Si lo saco del for, no "ve" a la variable y si lo meto dentro lo repite cuatro veces. Estoy dándole vueltas. Pero Muchas Gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: si por eso mi pregunta fue si de todas las columnas o una, pero que bueno que ya lo resolviste :D exito!!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte.